# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'guild' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, database, mongodb, discord.py, nextcord

I want to make something so that when script starts, it gets information about members in guilds like the id, guild id.

I have this code:

```
    async def on_ready(self):
        for guild in guild:
            for member in guild.members:
                values = {
                    "_id":member.id,
                    "guild_id":guild.id,
                    "warns": 0 ,
                    "reasons": []
                }
                server_values = {
                    "_id": guild.id,
                    "case": 0
                }
                if collusers.count_documents({"_id": member.id, "guild_id": guild.id}) == 0:
                    collusers.insert_one(values)    
                if collservers.count_documents ({"_id": guild.id}) == 0:
                    collservers.insert_one(server_values)
```

But I also get an error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andriyko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\client.py", line 351, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Andriyko\Desktop\Ghostbot\modules\warn.py", line 18, in on_ready       
    for guild in guild:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'guild' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: You'll likely need to pass `guild` as a parameter to your function, and `for a in a:` is at the very least going to be confusing (i.e. use different names for the loop variable and the collection variable).

Comment: Try `for guilds in self.client.guilds` instead of `for guilds in guilds`, or set guilds to self.client.guilds.

Comment: Okay, I will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't assign anything to variable `guild`. You can get all `guilds` that your bot is in with:

```py
for guild in self.client.guilds:
```

---

You can also get the guild object first (if you want to run it only for one guild) with:

```py
guilds = client.get_guild(id)

for guild in guilds:
    ...
```

Also, remember that you have to enable [`intents.Members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents.members) to get `guild.members`.